# 7 day rolling average using Unix seconds in Hive

Tags: hive, range, unix-timestamp

I need to find the 7 day rolling average of the temperature.

Using date strings provided in my dataset, I created a unix timestamp. I substituted the first time stamp on each day with the associated unix timestamp on midnight of that day.

[image: The data looks like this]

There are 604800 unix seconds in one week, so I tried using the following code to calculate it, but it did not work. How can I fix this code so it performs the window calculation correctly?

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS every_7_days;
CREATE VIEW every_7_days AS
SELECT weather_dt,
       time,
       fixed_unix_time,
       temperature,
       avg(temperature) OVER(ORDER BY fixed_unix_time RANGE BETWEEN 604800 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS roll7day_avg
  FROM clean_first_row
  ORDER BY fixed_unix_time;
```

Comment: Define *"it did not work"* - Did you get any errors? Or if the results were wrong, what exactly were you expecting and what actually was displayed. Show us the sample dates for the given range which you used to test the scenario as we only see the rows for one day in your sample. Also remember, always post examples in **text** format only  and **not** images, so that it's easier for others to reproduce your scenario.

Comment: When this step runs, it technically runs without any errors, however, when I try to print the table (SELECT * FROM every_7_days) I get this error:   org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: NullPointerException null