# Hive Average over Fixed Date Interval for Each Entry

Tags: hive

```
SELECT
date,
user_id,
AVG(value) OVER (
        PARTITION BY  user_id
        ORDER BY unix_timestamp(ftime,'yyyyMMddHH')
        RANGE BETWEEN 604800 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS value
FROM TABLE
```

I'm trying to get a 7 day average for each user in Hive, wondering why this isn't working:

Error in semantic analysis: line 1:205 Invalid Function 'yyyyMMddHH'

Comment: are you looking for last 7 days average ? then you can issue simple AVG() where date between last 7 days group by kind of clause. if you want every weekly average since date started, then your query may work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53687871/7-day-rolling-average-using-unix-seconds-in-hive might help you